# SharePoint 2013Visual WebPart with custom properties

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

**Solved. Read on...**

I can copy the code from this [MSDN aricle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231551.aspx) 1:1 and it does not work.
**I cannot see any custom property in the web part properties.**
Although there is no "Miscellaneous" category. There's only Appearance, Layout and Advanced.

```
namespace Tts.CareersPortal.Web.CareersPortal.Fn.WebParts.NewContactTeaserWebPart
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using MyNameSpace.NewContactTeaserWebPart;

    public partial class NewContactTeaserWebPartUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private int _contactTeaserCount;

        [Category("Extended Settings"),
        Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
        WebBrowsable(true),
        WebDisplayName("Sample Text"),
        WebDescription("Please Enter a Sample Text")]
        public int ContactTeaserTeaserCount
        {
            get
            {
                return _contactTeaserCount;
            }
            set
            {
                _contactTeaserCount = value;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IEnumerable<MyContact> contacts = LoadContactProperties();

            Repeater1.DataSource = contacts;
            Repeater1.DataBind();
        }

        private IEnumerable<MyContact> LoadContactProperties()
        {
            ContactFinder contactFinder = new ContactFinder(ContactTeaserTeaserCount);

            IEnumerable<MyContact> result = contactFinder.GetContact();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution:** I was adding the web part property to the wrong class file :-/ You have to add it to the webpart - not the user control. To pass along the webpart properties to the user control I recommend [this](http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/11/17/how-to-create-sharepoint-2010-custom-visual-webpart-properties/) following approach - others will work too.

Does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need help in creating a visual webpart in SharePoint 2010 using C#, follow [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36792/Developing-and-Deploying-Custom-Web-Parts-for-Shar)

If you need help with webpart property alone, try the following code:

```
public static string SampleText;
[Category("Extended Settings"),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("Sample Text"),
WebDescription("Please Enter a Sample Text")]
public string _SampleText
{
    get { return SampleText; }
    set
    {
        // Sample Validation
        Regex oRegEx = new Regex("[a-zA-Z]+");
        if (!oRegEx.IsMatch(value))
            throw new Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.
                WebPartPageUserException(
                "Please enter alphabeth characters only");
        SampleText = value;
    }
}
```

Also find the following article helpful in the same:
[Custom webpart properties](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/188019/Creating-Visual-Web-Part-Properties)

Comment: Argh! - codeproject link helped. I was adding the property to the wrong class file :< Although I CAN NOT recommend the codeproject article. Static fields and PersonalizationScope.User sounds like a bad idea. I like http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/11/17/how-to-create-sharepoint-2010-custom-visual-webpart-properties/ way more.

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowsable(true), makes it visible in webpart properties.
and this one Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared) define in what mode (shared or personalized) it will be visible.